# Which is the largest number out of these three$?$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, big-numbers

## Rayo's Number

The smallest number bigger than any finite number named by an expression in the language of first-order set theory with a googol symbols or less.

---

Now everyone knows that it is the largest number till date. But I've heard of some numbers that are even larger than Rayo's Number. The two of them are **Fish number $7$ and BigFoot**. I couldn't find their wikipedia so I can't attach their definitions.

Which number of three of them is the biggest $?$ Also, if someone can explain me the definition of Rayo's Number it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Rayo%27s_number and https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/BIG_FOOT and https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Fish_number_7 could be helpful links.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to compare such "numerical monsters" in their magnitude. Also, are those three numbers well defined at all ? The first should be , but what about the others ?

Comment: Fish number 7 is based off of Rayo's number, and is easily larger.